# How can I use dynamic allocation (malloc) with dual structure in C?

Tags: c, malloc, clang, structure, allocation

I want to know how I can use dynamic allocation (malloc) with dual structure in C.

I want to make a program which represents like this

> Input Subject1 Name : Math
>
> Input Subject2 Name : English
>
> Input Taker1 Name : Kim
>
> Input Taker2 Name : Park
>
> Input Taker3 Name : John
>
> Input Taker4 Name : David
>
> Input Taker5 Name : Kelly
>
> Input Taker6 Name : Fiona
>
> Input Taker7 Name : Amanda
>
> Input Taker8 Name : Sally
>
> Input Taker9 Name : Lee
>
> Input Taker10 Name : Kang
>
> -RESULT-
>
> Kim : Math, English
>
> Park : Math, English
>
> John : Math, English
>
> David : Math, English
>
> Kelly : Math, English
>
> Fiona : Math, English
>
> Amanda : Math, English
>
> Sally : Math, English
>
> Lee : Math, English
>
> Kang : Math, English

This is a code that I made which represents two structures relevant to each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SNUM 2          
#define TNUM 10             

typedef struct subscore {           
    char cname[SNUM][20];       
    int score[SNUM];                
} sscore;

typedef struct Taker {              
    char *name;                         
    sscore score;                   
} tTaker;

...

void main() {
    tTaker **teta[TNUM];
    create_Taker(teta);

    printf("-RESULT-\n");
    print_Taker(tTaker ** teta);
    ...

    delete_Taker(teta);
}


void create_Taker(tTaker ** teta) {

    char str[80];
    int len;

    for (int i = 0; i < SNUM; i++) {
        printf("Input Subject%d Name : ", i + 1);
        gets_s(str, 80);
        len = strlen(str) + 1;      
        teta[i]->score.cname = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len); // ERROR!     
        strcpy_s(tt[i]->score.cname, sizeof(char), str);    
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<TNUM; i++) {
        printf("Input Taker%d Name : ", i + 1);
        gets_s(str, 80);
        len = strlen(str) + 1;
        teta[i]->name = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);  
        strcpy_s(teta[i]->name, sizeof(char), str); 
    }
    getchar();  
}

...

void print_Taker(tTaker ** teta) {
        ...
}

void delete_Taker(tTaker **teta) {
    for (int i = 0; i < TNUM; i++) {        
        free(teta[i]->score.cname);         
        free(teta[i]->name);                    
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, Structure 'tTaker' includes another structure 'sscore'.
For this, I made a code like this :

```
void create_Taker(tTaker ** teta) {

    char str[80];
    int len;

    for (int i = 0; i < SNUM; i++) {
        printf("Input Subject%d Name : ", i + 1);
        gets_s(str, 80);
        len = strlen(str) + 1;      
        teta[i]->score.cname = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len); // ERROR!     
        strcpy_s(tt[i]->score.cname, sizeof(char), str);    
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<TNUM; i++) {
        printf("Input Taker%d Name : ", i + 1);
        gets_s(str, 80);
        len = strlen(str) + 1;
        teta[i]->name = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);  
        strcpy_s(teta[i]->name, sizeof(char), str); 
    }
    getchar();  
}
```

But, as you can see from the code, some problems happen because of this part :

`teta[i]->score.cname = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len); // ERROR!`

I made this code to try to make a dynamic allocation function... But It has many problems that I can't solve. I am using Visual Studio 2017 as IDE and this program printed this error message because of the part.

> warning C404
>
> error C2106 : left value should be l-value.

Sadly, debugging function from my Visual Studio doesn't work so there are no ways that I can get to solve this problem...

I want to make my problem to work like the example that I showed from the introduction part.

What is wrong with that part?
And I want to know that this function works correctly :

```
void delete_Taker(tTaker **teta) {}
```

I need your big helps. Thanks.

This is the picture which represents how the memory of the program looks like..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaJT9.png)

Comment: C is not easy to learn by trial&error. Better read a book, or take a tutorial.

Comment: "*`teta[i]->score.cname = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len); `*": `cname` is 2D-array of `char`. How come you want to assign a pointer to it. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: 1) `tTaker **teta[TNUM]; create_Taker(teta);` type mismatch. `create_Taker` requires `tTaker **`

Comment: Note that you invented a term, *dual structure*, what is it? If you mean two structures just say "*two structures*".

Comment: @lharob AI Asimi Sorry, My english is bad. I am a Korean so English is not my native language. So my English looks so ridiculous. I will keep your saying in mind! Thank you

Comment: @alk Then Don't I need to use malloc from the part!? I think I thought that with a strange way... I already found information about allocation and structure from many books in Korea, but I couldn't find information which can make me understand the problem still... That's why I asked a question here as the last way.

Comment: Change `char cname[SNUM][20]; ` to be `char * cname[SNUM];`. Also remove all those useless casts to `malloc()`, at least a long you really use a C compiler.

Comment: You will rarely need to use pointers to pointers (`**`) and this is not one of those times.  You can do this assignment with just single asterisks, and should.

Comment: For reference, the word for a structure inside another structure is *nested structure*.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for your advice. I will remove the double pointer parts and I will use another way to solve this problem. I am really trying to solve this problem although the reference sources are really few.

Comment: @alk Thank you! I will consult your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

** is a pointer to a pointer.

Example:

```
int a;
int *x = &a;
int **y = &x;
```

Here a is the variable. x is a pointer and has the address of a. and y is a pointer to pointer and has the address of pointer x.

The y cannot hold the address of variable a. ie `int **y=&a;` is INVALID.

Similarly if i do `printf("%d",*y);` it will printer the address of pointer x not the value inside a.

OK so coming onto your question.

`tTaker **teta[TNUM];` is a pointer to a pointer that can hold the address of any pointer to `tTaker`.

In this line `teta[i]->score.cname = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);` `teta[i]->score.cname` is INVALID because you cannot acess `score.cname` because teta is not a pointer to tTaker its a pointer to pointer.

***Also You have not initilized `tTaker **teta[TNUM];` , creation of pointer dosent mean creation of object. you need to allocate object and assign it to teta..***

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I will consult your explanation when I keep trying to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1108/pointers/11324/const-pointers